# VISUAL STUDIO 2010: How to output all projects under a solution to the same directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have inherited a C# application, it is made up of 4 solution files each with 92 projects under each solution file.

I am looking for an easy way to change all the Build Output Path's of each project to a common directory when I manually build the solutions.

If someone knows of either a macro that will iterate through each project and change the path, or if there is a way to create a global environment variable which will override all the projects' variables, or any other way, I will really appreciate the help.

Please note that I am NOT using a build server, and that I would like to accomplish this for when I do a manual build on the solution in visual studio.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Install a decent text editor, if you do not already have one.  Something like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).  The editor will need to be able to open multiple files at once.
2. Go to the parent solution directory in My Computer.
3. Enter "*.csproj" (or "*.vbproj") in the search bar to be able to open all project files in sub-directories at one time.

   [image]
4. Open your text editor, like Notepad++
5. Drag all project files into the editor to open them
6. Look for the `<OutputPath>...</OutputPath>` line and perform a find and replace in all open documents, replacing the path(s) that are there with the path you want.

   [image]

Comment: Thank you, brilliant and practical idea!

Comment: @Ryk: many ways to skin a cat, but if you just wanna get the path changed across the board this would be a quick, simple way to handle it.  Just be aware that you may have more than one different output path already in the project files to replace (e.g., "bin\Release" and "bin\Debug")

Comment: I'm using Sublime with the following regex: `<OutputPath>bin\\(Release|Debug)\\</OutputPath>` to find output paths, and then replace it with `<OutputPath>..\\bin\\\1\\</OutputPath>`

Answer (score 2):

The information about output location stored in project file (*.csproj)

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    **<OutputPath>..\..\Libs\CompiledLibs\</OutputPath>**
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
</PropertyGroup>
```

you can find tool to replcace/add that setting in all project files or write yourself updater...project file is XML file that can be mofified using C#.

Comment: thank you. I was hoping that I could avoid that. What you say will work, but I am hoping for something easier, as I already am in over my head in other things at the moment. If I cannot find any other way, I will award you the points, once again thank you.

Comment: I heard that Beyond Compare application has ruch abilities for text manipulation...possibly it will able to do it (replace ouputpath value in all xml files in folder and subfolders).